# IntelliJ downloads all the jars from my local maven repo to the system/jars folder

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am new to intelliJ and trying to import maven projects. IntelliJ downloads all the jars from my local maven repo to the system/jars folder. Which is getting huge.

How can i make sure it does not copies the jar from local maven repo to system/jars folder instead should resolve dependency from the local maven repo only

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?  I noticed this on an old install of IntelliJ 12, but a colleague who is running IntelliJ 14 doesn't seem to have the system/jars folder.

Answer (score -1):

Today I'v found that my system/jars folder is 6.6GB, maven dependencies which were updated are kept in jars folder even when not used. 
Is there a possibility to clean this folder from old dependencies?

Also it would be better to use dependencies from local maven repo rather than making duplicates.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).